# Python duplicate keys, cannot find keys in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key, duplicates, tuples

Guys this is very strange, and probably is some minor error I haven't managed to see:

So I have a dictionary with keys as tuples. Each key is a tuple of (state, action), where state is a tuple containing values and tuples. Action is a value.

I am loading my dictionary from file and it loads correctly. At a point during the program, it checks if a key exists. If it does, change the value, otherwise create dict[key] = 0.

The problem is this: The dictionary has a key (state, action) with a particular value. When I try to check if it exists using "in", it states that it does not exist. When I check with dict.keys(), it states it exists. I have also output dict.keys() and can verify that it does in fact exist.

Furthermore, if I compare values with other values (ex: dict[key] > secondValue) the program crashes. If I do dict[key] = secondValue, sometimes it does not change the value of the key but creates a duplicate key! Which then, dict.keys() returns two or more same keys. Here is some code:

```
    if (key not in self.currentDict):
                pass
                print "key not in self.currentDict"
                if key not in self.currentDict.keys():
                    print "key not in self.currentDict.keys()"
                else:
                    print "key in self.currentDict.keys()"
```

The above indentation is not an error, indentation is fine in the actual code.

Now each of these crash the program:

```
print "self.currentDict[key] = %s" % (self.currentDict[key])
if (self.currentDict[key] > value)
```

I seriously don't know why it's acting like this. If I start a new file, the program runs and saves to the file, it works correctly. If I use an existing file, therefore an existing dictionary, it either crashes or creates duplicates of keys (which a lot of sources state that is impossible).

Any ideas? Thanks!

--EDIT--

pass was only there before prints, it's not affecting with results

This is the last output I got from the program. Very sorry that the dictionary keys are quite long!

```
key not in self.currentDict

key in self.currentDict.keys()

key not in self.currentDict

self.currentDict = {
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.5): 0, 
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.6): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.7): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.7): -88.0, 
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.2): -96.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.6): -168.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.1): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.5): -91.2,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.8): -102.39999999999999,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.7): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.3): -113.6,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.2): -80.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.1): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.3): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.5): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.6): -96.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.8): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.4): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.4): -80.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.8): -104.8030982226376,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.8): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.1): -120.0, # <---------------
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.2): -96.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.5): -97.6,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.2): -96.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.4): -120.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.3): -107.19999999999999,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.6): -88.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.7): -96.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.4): -104.0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.1): 0,
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.3): -88.0}

self.currentDict.keys() = [
     (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.5),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.6),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.7),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.7),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.2),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.6),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.1),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.5),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.8),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.7),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.3),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.2),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.1),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.3),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.5),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.6),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.8),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.4),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.4),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.8),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.8),
      (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.1), # <-----------
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.2),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.5),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.2),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.4),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.3),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.6),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.7),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.4),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.1),
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.3)]
```

AND

```
key = (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.1)
```

type of self.currentDict = `<type 'dict'>`

I am obtaining self.currentDict by loading a dictionary of dictionaries from the file and deep-copying the last dictionary to self.currentDict.

I also executed this code:

```
    keyProblems = [k for k in self.currentDict.keys() if k not in self.currentDict]
    print "keys with problems: %s" %(str(keyProblems))
```

which returned this result:

```
    keys with problems: 
    [(((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.6), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.7), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.7), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.2), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.6), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.1), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.8), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.7), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.3), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.2), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.1), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.3), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.6), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.8), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.4), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.4), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.8), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.8), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 1.1), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.2), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.2), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.4), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.3), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.6), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.7), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 3.4), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 4.1), 
    (((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)), 2.3)]
```

Just to clarify, all the values above (including the actions) are discrete (no recurring floats)

Isolated the problem to be between two method calls. These methods are called sequentially from the application. At the end of the first method, there are no keys with problems. At the very beginning of the second method, a lot of keys have problems (as according to the above code). The problem is now even more mysterious than it was before :/

Update: I've tested the same exact program on another laptop, and surprisingly it runs flawlessly without any "key problems" even after tens of runs. These are the configurations on each laptop:

Laptop 1:

```
    Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1, 64-bit, i7-3610QM, 8GB RAM
    Running under Eclipse with PyDev, application's internal Python: Crashes + key problems
    Running directly from .bat file and outside Eclipse/Pydev, Pydev still installed: Crashes + key problems
    Running under Eclipse with Pydev, using Python 2.7 installed in drive C: Crashes + key problems
    Running directly from .bat file and outside Eclipse/Pydev, Pydev uninstalled: Crashes + key problems
```

Laptop 2:

```
    Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1, 64-bit, Dual Core T5550, 4GB RAM
    Pydev: Did not manage to test it with Pydev without having import errors
    Running directly from .bat file and outside Eclipse/Pydev, Pydev installed: Works correctly even after tens of runs, list of key problems always empty
```

I am using exact copies of the project directory and same paths for both laptops. Any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: Please post the dictionary (or a sample, if it's too small) and the key that you are checking

Comment: Could it have something to do with line terminations in the file you are reading from - these things can be finicky (CR vs CRLF vs LF depending on the OS). Wouldn't be the first time this caused a hard to track issue. Try dumping the strings as hex.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget just posted the dictionary :)

Comment: My eyes hurt. Please add some formatting to that `dict`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget added bold formatting for not found key (which is also in self.currentDict.keys())

Comment: You could try `[k for k in self.currentDict if k not in self.currentDict]`, it should be an empty list.

Comment: @tdelaney I think you meant [k for k in self.currentDict.keys() if k not in self.currentDict] right? I just executed that, and it's not an empty list...

Comment: yeah, I meant .keys(). Strange thing is, I tried it with your example dict (before it got edited away!) and all worked okay. I can't explain it. Is action a float or some class?

Comment: Yes, action is a float @tdelaney

Comment: You'll have problems with floats that don't serialize exactly (`>>> x=1./3;y=float(str(x));print x,y,x==y
 gives you 0.333333333333 0.333333333333 False`) but that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: @tdelaney although some values are floats, they cannot be recurring because all of them are discrete...just updated question because that wasn't clear.

Comment: Its just tuples, ints and floats (basic types) yet the test shows that the dict doesn't think any of its own keys are in itself. You say this is an app with python 2.7 built in, ... could they have screwed up the embedding? Is it cpython, jpython, ironpython? Try the same thing in regular python and then report bugs against the app.

Comment: @tdelaney Tried it and isolated the problem. It has nothing to do with the saving/loading or the inbuilt python. The method that loads the file and deep-copies the last dict to self.currentDict is called by a class as an object method. Exactly after self.currentDict is built, there are no keys with problems. After some time, it starts showing key problems (even though this dictionary is not touched outside of its class).

Answer (score 0):

I think you think that there's a difference between `self.currentDict` and `self.currentDict keys`... and that somehow the first is giving you the first element of your tuple, and the second one the second...

To check if a tuple exists as a key:

```
if ('state', 'value') in self.currentDict
```

And to assign, you should do:

```
self.currentDict[('state', 'value')] = 'some value'
```

(note: the parentheses aren't strictly necessary, but imho make it clearer)

Comment: I'm building the keys as tuples, so: 

stateTuple = convert state from list to tuple
action = action value
key = (stateTuple, action)

Comment: Just tried to do (self.currentDict[(stateTuple, action)] > value) but still got the same crash :/

Comment: @user2623934 elaborate on crash... copy and paste the error/traceback into your question

Comment: Cannot really...I'm building an extension of a program that has python 2.7 built-in without any docs, so all I get is "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way." @Jon Clements

Comment: @user2623934 that's information you should provide in your question...  as well as cleaning up and formatting your dictionary - remember it only needs a couple of lines as an example...